# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.shared.AbstractCmisHttpServlet

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, opencmis

I am working on a ready made cmis project which uses opencmis. I did maven build successfully but when I try to run this springboot App locally I get the above class-AbstractCmisHttpServlet not found error but I can see that file in my IDE/m2 repository. In the Applicattion java main file I get error in the method dispatcherServletRegistration() when I try to initialize this object new CustomCmisBrowserBindingServlet() this class extends AbstractCmisHttpServlet. Here it says the class not found.

**This is my POM details of opencmis`**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <overlays>
            <overlay />
            <overlay>
                <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
                <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings-war</artifactId>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- exclude everything you don't need -->
                    <exclude>index.html</exclude> <!-- default index page -->
                    <exclude>css/**</exclude> <!-- CSS for the default index page -->
                    <exclude>images/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>web/**</exclude> <!-- sample JavaScript application -->
                    <exclude>WEB-INF/classes/sample-repository.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </overlay>
        </overlays>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings-war</artifactId>
    <version>${opencmis.version}</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-server-support</artifactId>
    <version>${opencmis.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency><!-- for development only -->
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings</artifactId>
    <version>${opencmis.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**This is my main Application java file** `

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "local");
        SpringApplication.run(CMISApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CMISApplication.class, WebConfigurerAdapter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new
                CustomCmisBrowserBindingServlet(),
                "/api/cmis/browser/*");
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("callContextHandler",
                "com.sbs.digimags.browser.BearerAuthCallContextHandler");
        registration.setInitParameters(params);
        return registration;
    }



    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        // Added code to delete the cached files in the server during server start 
        File folder = new File(cacheFolder+key);
        LOG.info("Deleting cache files from"+ cacheFolder+key);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if(listOfFiles!=null ){
            for (int fileNumber = 0; fileNumber < listOfFiles.length; fileNumber++) {
                if (listOfFiles[fileNumber].isFile()) {

                    boolean deletionSuccess =listOfFiles[fileNumber].delete();
                    if(!deletionSuccess)
                        throw new CmisStorageException("Unable to delete the file");
                }
            }
        }
        servletContext.addListener(new CustomCmisRepositoryContextListener(env));
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }
```

Comment: Code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from the `chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings` dependency. In your setup, you need this jar.